# What is the difference between the Blackhole storage engine and the Example storage engine?

Tags: mysql, storage

I have briefly gone through the Blackhole and the Example storage engine code of mysql 5.5, and found that they are very similar with each other in many details.

I know that [The BLACKHOLE storage engine acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html), and [The EXAMPLE storage engine is a stub engine that does nothing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-storage-engine.html). But I've seen no significant difference between them.

So what is the essential difference between these two storage engine? And which one should I start with if I want to customize my own storage engine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning what should be considered as a starting point to build new engines, the doc is quite clear:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-storage-engine.html

> The **EXAMPLE** storage engine is a stub engine that does nothing. Its
>   purpose is to serve as an example in the MySQL source code that
>   **illustrates how to begin writing new storage engines**. As such, it is
>   primarily of interest to developers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I've read guidance from the book Understanding MySQL internal, chapter 7 storage engine interface, that is begin with blackhole storage engine, too. So I think I need to know the ultimate difference between them before making my own choice.